# access is denided on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

Good day!

I try to publish my web app on IIS , but i have some trouble:

Access is denided.

I tell you a story:)

I have static web site. At this site, works html form, wich send some text to admin(user find mistakes and send it to admin).
It sends via POST.

And at server side- i write mvc app , wich get POST request1,parse it and send it to admin address.
On local machine (with VS 2012) - it works well: i send POST (at html form) on [http://myhost.com:54566][1] (local host) and it sends email.

```
<form name="mistake" action="http://localhost:55457/" method=post>
    <input type="text" name="url" size="50" readonly="readonly">
    <br />
    <span class="text">
    Error :
    </span>
    <br /> 
    <textarea rows="5" name="mis" cols="37" readonly="readonly"></textarea> 
    <br />
    <span class="text">
    Comment :
    </span>
    <br /> 
    <textarea rows="5" name="comment" cols="37"></textarea> 
          
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="admin@admin.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Errors">
    <div style="margin-top: 7px"><input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input onclick="hide()" type="button" value="Close" id="close" name="close">        
    </div>
</form>
```

Then i try to publish it on IIS (Winserver 2012):
create Web Site, create Virtual Directory(manually) , copy web app into folder.
Make Anonimous authentication = Enabled (on appm site and server).

Add on neighboring folder - my static site (StaticSite).Make same rules.
And on server - run static page, send text via POST request on server :

```
<form name="mistake" action="http://web-server:8888/WebApp/Email/Create" method=post>
```

/Email/Create :

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
    // TODO: Add insert logic here
    var allKeys = collection.AllKeys;
    var Keys = collection.Keys;
    var pairs = collection.Count;
    var pageURL = collection.GetValue("url");
    var mistake = collection.GetValue("mis");
    var comment = collection.GetValue("comment");
    var email = collection.GetValue("email");
    var subject = collection.GetValue("subject");        

    String pageStr = pageURL.AttemptedValue + "\n\n\n";
    String mistakeStr = mistake.AttemptedValue + "\n\n\n";
    String dateStr = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "\n\n\n";
    String commentStr = comment.AttemptedValue + "\n\n\n";
    String userName = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).Identity.Name + "\n\n\n";
        
    String body = pageStr + userName + mistakeStr + dateStr + commentStr;
            
    MyEmail mistakeEmail = new MyEmail(Config.GetSMTP(), Config.GetAddressFrom(), email.AttemptedValue, subject.AttemptedValue, body);
    mistakeEmail.SendMessage();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And then i get error:

> Access is denied.
> Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL.
>
> Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.

Please, tell me how to fix this problem!
Thank you!

EDIT: i change auth methid- to Windows auth Enabled. It seems to works,but then over some time - Windows auth- Disabled...

Comment: Try to enable Integrated Windows Authentication on your IIS web site or directory.

Comment: I do that.- no results.

Comment: And i havent any Authorize attribute on controller method.

Comment: Key here is this: `Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.` Does a simple test page work at all? The website/application pool configuration may need to be reviewed, it probably has nothing to do with your code, just the configuration of the new IIS server to match your local environment.

Comment: Can you share your web.config?